# Spring Cloud Data Flow multiple input output

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-kafka, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow

Im trying to create a PROCESSOR that take in input one parameter and I want it to produce multiple outputs, in this case two. I have defined it like this with a costum interface

```
public interface MyProcessor {

    String INPUT = "myInput";

    @Input
    SubscribableChannel myInput();

    @Output("myOutput")
    MessageChannel anOutput();

    @Output
    MessageChannel anotherOutput();
}
```

and than the application logic like this, just return the input parameter

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBinding(MyProcessor.class)
public class SpringDataFlowAppApplication {

     Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringDataFlowAppApplication.class);


    @Autowired
    private MyProcessor processor;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringDataFlowAppApplication.class, args);
    }

    @StreamListener(MyProcessor.INPUT)
    public void routeValues(String val) {

        processor.anOutput().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(val).build());
        processor.anotherOutput().send(MessageBuilder.withPayload(val).build());

        logger.debug("SpringDataFlowAppApplication --> "+val);
    }
}
```

Now the question is, how to connect two other processors in this outputs like in the figure. I want to parallelize some processes (PROC_! and PROC_2). For the deployment Im using SpringCloudDataFlow Console as in the image below
[image]

Comment: Hi, This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854655/multi-output-binding-in-spring-cloud-data-flow

Comment: Yes you have right, but graphicaly how to parellelize the stream?

Comment: Currently, SCDF Dashboard doesn't have graphic (via Flo) support for handling mutliple input/outputs. You can still create and deploy streams that represents the multiple input/output flow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [multi output binding in spring cloud data flow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854655/multi-output-binding-in-spring-cloud-data-flow)

Comment: Any update on this? We are trying to achieve the same.

Comment: Any update on this how to have graphic dashboard handling multiple input processors on ui side (using flo or any other alternative)? We are trying to achieve the same.  @ilayaperumal-gopinathan

Comment: @NarendraKumar no nothing